# Admin-User defined data validation

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a web app. One of the requirements is that there is some data validation.

[Example Table](https://jsfiddle.net/Bigmuddyfoot/by5Lsg2n/1/)

99% of the validation is going to be IF... AND, OR, NOT, <,>.

I can build the JS functions to do it but the roadblock I'm running into is that I don't want to have to program all these for this customer all the time. I want the site admins to be able to build the if statements.

my original thought is the user would use a forum that would allow them to build a proper if statement with forum validation/restrictions and that would save to a DB then i would just pull that data on the fly into my code and the if statements would run and that would be that.

But apparently it is extremally hard or impossible from what i have read to make this happen. As it poses a security issue.

And this is where my exception comes in. This is not a public accessible site and id its hosted on an internal server behind a VPN and SSO/MFA.

Only site admins will have the ability to create these if statements and they will be restricted to options that are provided in the forum (see attached image).[image: forum input for if statement]

I don't mind adding character stripping and only allowing certain character to be used for better protection.

My problem is i cant get the code to run when pulling the if statements from a db.

Here is an example of how im trying to load the JS code for valadation

```
<script>
var ifStatements = <?php echo json_encode($ifStatements); ?>;
console.log(ifStatementLoaded); 
</script>
```

Comment: Try `ifStatements = JSON.parse(ifStatements);`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Array to hold all the cat_num values in the table
    var cat_nums = [];

    // Iterate over each cat_num element in the table
    $('.cat_num').each(function() {
        // Extract the cat_num value and push it to the cat_nums array
        cat_nums.push($(this).text().trim());
    });

    // Load validation conditions from PHP script using AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_condition.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // Process the received data
            console.log('Validation conditions:', data);

            // Loop through each condition
            data.forEach(function(condition) {
                // Dynamically evaluate the condition_expression from the database
                if (eval(condition.condition_expression)) {
                    // Display the alert message
                    alert(condition.alert);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('Error fetching validation conditions:', error);
        }
    });
});
```

In the DB i stored values as the following

```
if (cat_nums.includes("65165420")) {
    alert("Message here");
}
```

for what im doing right now the includes works fine if you need a little more control you may want to remove that and use a == or === for better control.